# How can I execute adb connect command in robot framework?

Tags: python, command-line, appium, adb, robotframework

Is there any way I could execute these command lines in robot frame work?

---

adb -s ### kill-server

adb -s ### start-server

adb connect ###

adb -s ### uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server

adb -s ### uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test

---

(### shows the device name)

robotframework 　python

Library：AppiumLibrary

Appium version:1.21.0

Desktop OS version to run appium:mac 13.6

device: Galaxy watch 5

I had some error when executing test of android device, and I found out that these command lines would solve problems. However, I have to manually type these command lines every time an error occurs.
If  there is some kind of way I could solve this automatically I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process allows you to run any command, so you can run `adb` as

```
${result} = Run Process adb -s ### kill-server
```